# Nested cycle in Rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have nested grids in my views and would like to use same CSS classes for each grid. When I use two nested `cycle( "odd", "even" )` helpers I get messed CSS like three rows with `odd` class

Sample grid

```
<% first_collection.each do |entry| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle( "odd", "even" ) %>">
    # some info here
    <% entry.records.each do |record| %>
      <div class="<%= cycle( "odd", "even" ) %>">
        <%= record.value %>
      </div>
    <% end %> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

so the question - is it possible to have two same nested cycles which don't mess with each other ?

Comment: Try having a look at the api.rubyonrails.org documentation on it. It shows an example on using a nested one. (Sorry not sure how to link it from the frame setup). Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but you seem to be using the equal sign on your loop method calls, i dont think it needs to be there. Maybe it's just the way the code got pasted in, but you seem to be missing an <% end %> as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can apply a name to each cycle call to keep them separate.

```
<% first_collection.each do |entry| %>
  <tr class="<%= cycle( "odd", "even", :name => 'first_collection ) %>">
    # some info here
    <% entry.records.each do |record| %>
      <div class="<%= cycle( "odd", "even", :name => 'entries' ) %>">
        <%= record.value %>
      </div>
    <% end %> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```